# C++ lazy way to find union of std::sets

Tags: c++, stl, set, addition

I want to find the union of two sets, ie add them together. I am aware of `.insert()` and `std::set_union()`, but, as far as I can tell, these require one to first obtain an iterator to the beginning and end of the second set (or worse for `set_union()`). It would be nice if I could just do something like `+` and `+=`; it seems like that would be a fairly obvious feature for a class that implements the mathematical concept of a set. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Can you show an example of code you'd like to be able to write? The question's not too clear as is.

Comment: `set::begin` and `set::end` has constant time complexity. What do you have against them?

Comment: @C.R. lack of concision

Comment: I would define a namespace lazy_stl, define your operator+ in there in terms of std::set_union and add "using namespace lazy_stl;" everywhere :) Edit: Hmmm on second thought you'll probably have to define it in std (which is not allowed iirc) or explicitly scope it, which will ruin the whole point. (due to ADL)

Comment: Short answer: no. But you can write it yourself easily enough, if you really find `s1.insert(s2.begin(),s2.end())` too verbose.

Comment: @C.R. Ah, I'm just a layman. Any suggestion for something more clear?

Comment: there is a way! overload operator+ and operator+= to do the operation of set_union for your

Comment: @Claudiordgz: In which namespace do you think that should be done? Can't put it in `std::` and everywhere else you break ADL (Koenig lookup)

Comment: what's wrong with doing an overloading that receives type operator+(std::set<> const &lhs, std::set<> const&rhs) and performs the same set_union inside? put it in header only as a template and now you have a tool which everyone can use until this behavior is standard, then you change the namespace to std and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any ways to simplify it with existing C++ methods.

One way to simplify container algorithms that operate on the whole container is to wrap them in a template method accepting a container:

```
template <typename T>
void my_union(const T& cont1, const T& cont2, T& cont3)
{
    // Make the union and store the result in cont3
}
```

If you want to have an operator for this, you can easily define one yourself:

```
template <typename T>
inline set<T>& operator+=(set<T>& lhs, const set<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs.insert(begin(rhs), end(rhs));
    return lhs;
}

template <typename T>
inline set<T> operator+(set<T> lhs, const set<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

int main() {
    set<int> a = {1, 2, 3   };
    set<int> b = {   2, 3, 4};

    a += b;

    for (auto i : a)
         cout << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

The above example will print `1 2 3 4` to the console.